# What happened to the teacher?

Tags: steganography, letters

One day, you go to school to find that your teacher is gone, and there is a substitute teacher instead. The substitute says, “Sadly, Mrs. Chunflower can not make it today, but she told me to still give you your tests. I hope you all studied!” As the class groans, she passes the test out. The test has 5 questions:

Whk ate the musicil pie?
Why id happiness alnays blue?
Wha is your favprite color?
Is a flpwer online or tall?
When ded the bowl eat a pdt?
Bonus: What is the secret message?

You wondered why there are so many spelling mistakes, as your teacher is lazy and always copies the tests from online. Why are there spelling mistakes, and what happened to the teacher?

I will accept for answers to all questions, although the test questions have no correct answer.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The teacher

> Got kidnapped!

Looking at:

> the typos in the test:
>
>  Wh**k** ate the music**i**l pie? Why i**d** happiness al**n**ays blue? Wh**a** is your fav**p**rite color? Is a fl**p**wer online or tall? When d**e**d the bowl eat a p**d**t? Bonus: What is the secret message?

Why are there spelling mistakes, and what happened to the teacher?

> The teacher got kidnapped, and hid the secret message in the test so that the class would save her!

Here's the answer key to the test.

Whk ate the musicil pie?

> The musicil pie eater.

Why id happiness alnays blue?

> Dopamine reflects blue light, obviously.

Wha is your favprite color?

> Blue, because it is the happiest color.

Is a flpwer online or tall?

> Yes.

When ded the bowl eat a pdt?

> Never, because bowls can't eat.

Bonus: What is the secret message?

> "Kidnapped"

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I suppose that makes more sense. Although the questions don't seem to make much sense regardless :)

Comment: Are you going to make up your own answers for the test questions?

Comment: @ZaniXu Sure, I can do that.

Comment: Ding! Accepted and upvoted